# SignalR - OnConnect() authorization - how to disconnect unauthorized user?

Tags: signalr

In my hub, I have something like this (pseudocode):

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    var isLegal = Authorize();
    if (!isLegal) //not authorized
    {
        //how do I deny him this connection?
    }
    return base.OnConnected();
}
```

How to disconnect/deny connection to a user?

Comment: can you not do the authorization in the controller/action level ? I mean block the user in the controller action, so that only the authorized users will be able to connect to the hub...

Answer (score 2):

Add authorize attribute over the class,the user will be denied, if not authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

The following link explains how to do Hub authentication and authorization.

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security

If you choose not to use the existing auth mechanism, you'll need to check if the user is authorized in every hub method and return appropriate messages.